error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 for
Getting following error on .net 4.8 project when it is build from powershell command
error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format
my Project looks like following
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

And powershell command is like below
Add-Content $BuildOutput (msbuild "$RepoDirectory\src\MyProject.Api.csproj" /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath="$ReleaseDirectory\MyProject.Api")

What version of msbuild are you using? Have you tried adding the namespace suggested in the error? Did it fix the problem?

It would appear that a very old version of MSBuild is being invoked. What does msbuild --version report? Support for SDK style projects was introduced in v15 of MSBuild. Your project is an SDK style project and needs v15 or newer.
